# Политика конфиденциальности для приложения

Tags: android

Приложение требует указать ссылку на документ о политике безопасности. Хотел бы узнать что писать в этом документе? Есть ли пример? Мое приложение требует разрешение android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Answer (score 8):

Создайте обычную html страничку типа (пункты можно варьировать в зависимости от функций заложенных в приложении):

### Privacy policy 
Политика конфиденциальности

1. Термин “личная информация”, используемый в настоящем документе, определяется как любая информация, которая идентифицирует или может использоваться для идентификации, связи или поиска человека, к которому такая информация относится. Личная информация, которую мы собираем, будет являться предметом настоящей политики конфиденциальности, с вносимыми время от времени поправками.

2. Мы не запрашиваем Ваш адрес электронной почты, телефон или какую нибудь информацию о Вас.

3. Мы не продаем контент.

4. Мы не требуем регистрации.

5. Безопасность Вашей персональной информации не будет нарушена.

6. Мы не просим информацию о местоположении через наше мобильное приложение.

7. Мы не отправляем на электронную почту рассылку новостей.

### Требуемые разрешения

1. Доступ к звонкам используется для таких-то целей (укажите для каких).

2. Доступ к контактам телефона используется для таких то целей (укажите для каких).

### Контакты

e-mail: support@domen.ru

Разместите ее в Интернете на любом хостинге (можно бесплатном) и укажите ссылку для приложения в консоли разработчика.

Comment: А если грузить html страницу из assets?

Comment: @Flippy из каких assets? Вы же не собираетесь ее в приложение интегрировать. Privacy policy - это внешняя страница в Интернете (к примеру на вашем сайте) с политикой безопасности для приложения. ссылка на нее указывается при размещении приложения в консоли разработчика Google.

Comment: Спасибо, примерно так и сделал